# Get third parameter in asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes

I have a asp.net MVC website, and I have this url:

```
Home/Index/
```

There is one action that I want to do, and currently I'm doing it using query string, like this:

```
Home/Index/?action=1
```

I'll then get it in my code using `Request.QueryString["action"]`.

But this does not look as good as it should, I'd like to have something like this:

```
Home/Index/Action
```

So the query string would be a third parameter. How can I use it like this and check if the third parameter exists, and it's name?

My routes are configured like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Do I need to change anything on the routes or I can just enter the way I want, and if so, how do I retrieve this value?

---

**Edit :**

Alright. What I wanted to do was to have a different result in the view depending on this parameter.

What I did now was create two `ActionResults` that use the same View sending different values to the `ViewData`.

Comment: I think you can achieve it by using routing attributes with asp.net web api 2. https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2 and here are the details for mvc attribute routing https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In MVC there is the concept of Model Binding, where the names of the parameters are used and then filled with values from the Form, without you having to do it.

If you write your Action method like this:

```
public ActionResult Index(int action)
{ ... }
```

then it will already work for `/Home/Index?action=1`.

If you want to be able to call it like `/Home/Index/1` then the easiest way is to simply write the Action method like this:

```
public ActionResult Index(int id)
{ ... }
```

This works because the `MapRoute` definition basically says 'if there is something after the {action} part (which in this case is "Index", by the way), then give it the parameter name {id} and bind it to the {id} parameter of my Action method".

**Update**:
The problem with using a parameter called **`action`** in *both* calling scenarios is that **`{action}`** is a special keyword in MVC.
To use `MySpecialParam` for both calling scenarios, you could just add this Route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default_MySpecialParam",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{MySpecialParam}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", MySpecialParam = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

However if **`MySpecialParam`** were to become **`action`**, then there is a name resolution conflict that MVC probably won't know how to handle, or it may even throw an error.

Comment: Check this comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40741029/get-third-parameter-in-asp-net-mvc#comment68708248_40741205

Answer (score 0):

The action is supposed to be right after the controller, usually. I think in your case it might be better to add a new controller, which has the action you want.

Comment: The thing is, I need to use the same view. DO you think it's better if I have two actions that use the same view, passing similar data?

Answer (score 0):

I gave up mapping routes as this is cumbersome. You need to add a new route for every number of parameters, like follows:

```
routes.MapRoute(
        "ThreeIds",                                  // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{firstId}/{secondId}/{thirdId}" // URL with parameters

        );

routes.MapRoute(
        "Dates",                                // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{startDate}/{endDate}"      // URL with parameters

        );
```

Try doing ajax calls using something like jQuery instead. No nead to add a route for every possibility.

```
$.ajax({
            url: '../' + controller + '/' + method,
            data: jsonObjectString,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'json',               
            success: function (data) {
                //do something
            },
            error: function (err) {
               //do something
            }
        });
```

You can use my library at https://github.com/Biot-Savart/MVC-DataCall.js to make life a bit easier.